# WSL2 update and apt-get failure, though ping works fine

Tags: apt, 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to get Ubuntu running using WSL2 on my office laptop.

***Problem:***
When I try to run apt-get update or any install command, eg: apt-get install gcc, it always ends up with `101: Network is unreachable`.

Solutions I have tried so far:

1. **Firewall**

   My initial guess was that my office firewall may be blocking the connection, but on quick ping check I see that it works fine. Also I have browsed the URLs in chrome and it works without any issues.

   ```
   $ ping 91.189.91.39
   PING 91.189.91.39 (91.189.91.39) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from 91.189.91.39: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=256 ms
   64 bytes from 91.189.91.39: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=256 ms
   ^C
   --- 91.189.91.39 ping statistics ---
   2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 255.540/255.757/255.975/0.217 ms
   ```
2. **resolver configuration file issue.**

   I have tried changing the default nameserver to 8.8.8.8 and other DNS providers as well but didn't resolve the issue. Also since ping works, DNS resolver shouldn't be a problem.

---

Now there are few more solution which I am able to find, like forcing apt to use IPv4, deleting hypervisor switching adapter and other such solutions but their problem doesn't seem to corelate with what I am facing and I don't want to keep shooting arrows in dark.

Any help or direction pointing will be very much appreciated.
Thank you

**Error log:**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1b). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::1c). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.191), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.150), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.15), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1b). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::1c). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.191), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.150), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.15), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**Error log by forced IPv4 usage :**

```
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.191), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.150), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.15), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.191), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.150), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.15), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5976  https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6753

Comment: Thanks for your comment @JohanPalych. But I followed the issue links and some other links that it refers to but i think there is no solution for the same as of now. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: Can you try it from home (or anywhere else) while not connected to the company network?  Also, is there any VPN involved?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes...I have tried that connecting from my home network...It gives same issue. We do use VPN,but when I am using WSL I disconnect the VPN.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to comment the question with these information but my reputation is too low to do it. I suggest to give a try to [wsl-vpn](https://github.com/AmmarRahman/wsl-vpn) which is a networking solution I've seen solving issues in many similar use cases (ping/ICMP working, HTTP/HTTPS/DNS/etc. not working) It leverages [moby-vpnkit](https://github.com/moby/vpnkit) and [npiperelay](https://github.com/jstarks/npiperelay) and it works by creating a "data-tunnel" between WSL2 and the Windows host, specifically a pipe. This means a Windows service is always listening. You get the best of almo

Comment: Let me try that as soon as I am back from vacation. Thanks for your input though @mrq

Comment: Above method actually requires to install docker, which I will not be able to due to company policies. Thanks for the solution though.